# ¿Porque cuando intento correr mi aplicacion en el telofono se cierra?

Tags: android

pues actualmente estoy usando android studio y basicamente cuando agrego los EditText, Botones y Textview en el diseño no me sale ningun error pero cuando agrego codigo al Onclick para que se ejecute dicho evento en un boton se me cierra la app en el telefono  y quisiera saber cual es el error me han dicho que es por mi codigo debe tener algun error logico o asi pero en realidad no, mi codigo no tiene errores y no se cual otro error sea

```
public class divisas1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button casa;
    private Button ok;
    private Button clean;
private EditText txt;
private TextView dol;
    private TextView eu;
    private TextView yn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_divisas1);
        casa.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        ok.findViewById(R.id.aceptar);
        clean.findViewById(R.id.borrar);
        txt.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        dol.findViewById(R.id.dolares);
        eu.findViewById(R.id.euros);
        yn.findViewById(R.id.yenes);

        casa.setOnClickListener(this);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        clean.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try{
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.aceptar:
                    String pl =txt.getText().toString();
                    double pesos=Double.parseDouble(pl);
                    double d,y,e;
                    d=pesos/17;
                    dol.setText(""+d);
                    e=pesos/20;
                    eu.setText(""+e);
                    y=pesos/0.17;
                    yn.setText(""+y);



                    break;
                case R.id.borrar:
                    dol.setText("");
                    eu.setText("");
                    yn.setText("");
                    break;

                case R.id.menu:
                    Intent mmm= new Intent(divisas1.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(mmm);
                    this.finish();
                    break;




            }




        }catch (Exception ignored){

        }
    }
}
```

Encuentran algun error a este codigo?

Comment: ¿Te ha dado algún error javascript? Porque estoy viendo la plantilla aquí (http://tafseer.asiandevelopers.com/demos/shifen/) y tiene pinta de que no se está generando bien el menú

Comment: Bienvenido Diego, podrias editar la pregunta y copiar lo que te muestra el logcat

Comment: Es importante agregues tu código o el mensaje de error como comenta Raul. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**

Comment: aqui esta el codigo realmente no se cual es el problema es una barra deslizable y como tiene dos activitys desde la activity principal llamo ala segunda activity que es el de divisas1 pero la llamo con el metodo de Intent

Comment: Acostumbra agregar el código como texto no como imagen, eso ayudará a que más desarrolladores analicen rápidamente tu problema.Además si revisas dentro del LogCat rápidamente encontrarás un mensaje que te indica mas sobre el error! :)

Comment: En el LogCat los mensajes de error se filtran con "Error" y el más importante es que el indica el Texto "Caused by", agrega el texto del código en lugar de imágenes, esto para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores y agrego una respuesta que te parece diego ? @diiegojuarez =)

Comment: eso intento hacer amigo pero si le aprieto en LogCat aparece mi dispositivo conectado y le pongo en filtros error pero no sale ningun error hasta que inicia la app en mi dispositivo y se cierra me aparece el error que escribi ahi arriba podrias ayudarme como encontrar el error en el LogCat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que las referencias de las vistas se están obteniendo incorrectamente, al asignar los listener a las variables casa, ok, clean estos tienen valor null:

```
Button casa, ok, clean;
EditText txt;
TextView dol, ey, yn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_divisas);

        //obten referencias de las vistas dentro de activity_divisas.xml

        casa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu);
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aceptar);
        clean = (Button)findViewById(R.id.borrar);

        txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto);

        dol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dolares);
        eu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.euros);
        yn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yenes);


        //Asigna listener!
        casa.setOnClickListener(this);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        clean.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

---

es importante mencionar que estas vistas deben encontrarse dentro del archivo `activity_divisas.xml` y deben de ser del tipo que definiste en la variable.

Por ejemplo dentro del archivo `activity_divisas.xml` debe encontrarse un botón con id `menu`.

```
casa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo realmente no sabia cual era el error en mi codigo pero veo que es por la declaracion de referencias entonces para solucionar este error debo colocarlos asi como  el ejemplo de :
casa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu)

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, solo era que no obtenías los valores de las vistas correctamente, por cierto gracias por modificar tu pregunta te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas como funciona el sitio y de paso [ask], saludos!.